# Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership working the way I need it to in Expression

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I am writing a PowerShell script to pull an AD report of user information. Most of the report works just fine, but I'm having issues getting group membership to work right.

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -identity | select name
```

works on its own to give me just a clean list of permissions, but piping the info into select name doesn't work inside of my expression. It just returns nothing. How can I filter only the name for each group, while still passing in each user to be processed.

So far nothing I have tried has been able to return a formatted list. I always end up with either too much data, or an empty column. I've also tried playing around with cleaning up the data after the fact, but I haven't been able to get the regex to do what I want it to do. My (non-functional) rough draft of this is listed below.

```
#Clean up Group Membership data
$test = Import-Csv $csvfile

$test | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group_Membership = $_.Group_Membership.Replace('(?<=OU=").*?(?=/,)', ' ')
    $_.Group_Membership = $_.Group_Membership.Replace('(?<=DC=").*?(?=/,)', ' ')
}

$test | Export-Csv $csvfile -NoType
```

```
$AllADUsers = Get-ADUser -Server $ADServer -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties * -Filter *

$AllADUsers |
    Select-Object @{Label="First Name";Expression={$_.GivenName}},
        @{Label="Last Name";Expression={$_.Surname}},
        @{Label="Display Name";Expression={$_.DisplayName}},
        @{Label="Username";Expression={$_.SamAccountName}},
        @{Label="Job Title";Expression={$_.Title}},
        @{Label="Company";Expression={$_.Company}},
        @{Label="Email";Expression={$_.Mail}},
        @{Label="Account Status";Expression={if (($_.Enabled -eq 'TRUE')) {'Enabled'} else {'Disabled'}}},
        @{Label="Last LogOn Date";Expression={$_.LastLogonDate}},
        @{Label="Group_Membership";Expression={$_.SamAccountName | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership}} |
    Export-Csv -Path $csvfile -NoTypeInformation
```

After running this script, I want a CSV file that lists the information above and just a list of security groups, but the way it's working now, I am getting everything, and it's messy.

Comment: `$_.SamAccountName | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` -> `(Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_.SamAccountName | Select-Object -Expand Name) -join ';'`?

Comment: This works well. Very clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested here - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485215/powershell-how-to-grep-command-output), you can use

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -identity test | out-string -stream | sls -caseSensitive "name"
```

Comment: The comment from Ansgar above is clean and works, but this works too with a little cleanup.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Both suggestions here will work for what I'm doing.